# How Do I Implement LocationClient within Intent Service?

Tags: android, location, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services, location-provider

I'm a noob to android development and I am trying to figure out how to use the Fused Location Provider.  I'm using [this](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html) tutorial and have no issues implementing as the tutorial shows.  However, now I want to get my last location from within an intent service.  The problem is that a new instance of Location Client is not accepting context or context.getApplicationContext() as parameters for ConnectionCallbacks and ConnectionFailedListner.  GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks and GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener are implemented with their accompanying methods.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

MY CODE

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener{...

private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //Checking for message type
    //Received geofence coordinates
    if (message.contains("Your parent is acquiring your current location")){

        c = context;
    //Force get location                
    locationclient = new LocationClient(c,c,c);//<--Not working 
    locationclient = new LocationClient(c,c.getApplicationContext(),c.getApplicationContext());//<--Not working 
    locationrequest = LocationRequest.create();   
    locationrequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);                locationclient.connect();


    }else{...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How Do I Implement LocationClient within Intent Service?

You wouldn't. `LocationClient`'s API is asynchronous, which does not work well with `IntentService`. Use a regular `Service`, manage your own background thread as needed, and call `stopSelf()` when you no longer need the service.

> The problem is that a new instance of Location Client is not accepting context or context.getApplicationContext() as parameters for ConnectionCallbacks and ConnectionFailedListner.

You have to pass in implementations of those listener interfaces.

> GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks and GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener are implemented with their accompanying methods

Not on `Context` and not on `Application`. You did not write those classes -- Google did. You cannot implement those interfaces on those classes as a result.

Somewhere, perhaps, you *did* implement those interfaces, in which case you need to pass an instance of that object (or objects, plural) to the appropriate methods.

Comment: the two first answers you give seem quite clear to me. But I don't understand when you say "...you need to pass an instance of that object (or objects, plural) to the appropriate methods." 
I think this approach is a very basic concept in Android - but like I said, I don't can apply it to my programs. Do you have any good advice for me? If you have any good website where I can read more about this, please let me know.

Comment: @MartinPfeffer: "Do you have any good advice for me?" -- ummmmm... objects, methods, classes, and interfaces are core Java concepts. What **specifically** do you not understand?

Comment: Well, actually I've set up my application to receive location updates (at my background service), this works fine but when I disable my phone's location-settings onDisconnected doesn't get called. So I think I have to implement this listener somewhere else - not in the service. Is this correct?

Comment: okay... reading the documentation brought me to a new "idea" what my mistake could be. onDisconneced -> "Called when the client is disconnected. This can happen if there is a problem with the remote service (e.g. a crash or resource problem causes it to be killed by the system). When called, all requests have been canceled and no outstanding listeners will be executed. " ... but how can I simulate this scenario?

Comment: @MartinPfeffer: "onDisconnected doesn't get called" -- perhaps you are not being disconnected. I would not assume that `onDisconnected()` would be called in the situation that you describe. To draw an analogy: you are talking on the phone with somebody. That person puts the phone down and wanders off. Your call is not disconnected, because neither you nor the other person hung up the phone.

Comment: @MartinPfeffer: Also note that the classes referred to in this question and answer are officially deprecated now, though Google has done a lousy job of documenting their replacements. :-(